# Safety tips when leaving luggage and papers behind

Tags: tips-and-tricks, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with your valuables on a low-cost holiday while swimming/diving?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/what-to-do-with-your-valuables-on-a-low-cost-holiday-while-swimming-diving)

As backpacker, one does not carry all his luggage to every location, especially when visiting a certain city or the like. Some people gave me advice on how to hide/lock/store my luggage and valuable papers.

- Stick your passport at the underside of a table with tape (as it is not recommended to bring it with you);
- Use trainstation lockers for your luggage (when available);
- Always carry visa/ creditcards/ money on your body;
- Never consult any maps in public, take a seat in a café to prevent a 'strayed' look.
- etc.

Does anyone know more handy "safety regulations" to take in consideration while backpacking?

I assume this should be a community wiki, as there is no right answer...

Comment: Never consult a map in public? I don't think this particular advice is practical. Am I supposed to learn the map and guidebook by heart before setting out? I am not Jason Bourne :)

Comment: Most of the answers for this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/what-to-do-with-your-valuables-on-a-low-cost-holiday-while-swimming-diving are relevant in your case

Comment: ah, yes indeed. thank you, I suppose this one can close.

Comment: @Grzenio This falls under the category of "don't look like a tourist".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not be so paranoid about having your passport stolen. It's far more common to lose your passport than have it stolen, so keeping it in a safe pocket in your backpack should be good enough for most cases. You'll be more likely to forget your passport if you stick it under a table when leaving in a hurry.  Sometimes a genuine Samaritan may find the passport, think it's lost, then turn it over to someone.

Try to minimize valuable items that you take with you when you're going backpacking. If you have to carry valuables such as a lot of cash (again, try to withdraw from cards instead, etc) then try to book hostels which offer a locker facility. Remember that many hostels require you to bring your own locks for the lockers.